# Choose the line spread of a particular font size

Tags: fontsize, paragraphs, line-spacing

Suppose that (say) I am writing text of size `\large` but want the line spread associated to the `\huge` size. How do I do that?

Obviously, I want a solution that works in gerater generality, that is, for all the standard sizes `\tiny`, `\small`, `\footnotesize`, `\Huge`, etc. I know I can just use `\linespread` to choose any line spread I want; but what if I want exactly the one that my particular documentclass uses for, say, `\huge`?

And if you absolutely *must* have a MWE, here is one:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newcommand\linespreadof[1]{%
%abracadabra, magic happening!
}

\begin{document}

\large\linespreadof{\huge} This paragraph has large text size, but has even huger line spread.

\huge\linespreadof{\tiny} The text size here is huge, but the line spread is so tiny that the
result will probably be overlapping lines. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really need the overlapping in the small case, as that's a lot harder as TeX switches from \baselineskip to \lineskip to avoid that happening even if you set baselineskip to 0pt

Comment: No, I don't think I'm actually going to ned that. It was mostly meant as an instructve example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tex makes overlapping hard, as it does not obey `\baselineskip` if it would require negative spacing and instead inserts `\lineskip` between each line, giving up a fixed space between each baseline.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setlength\textwidth{5cm}

\begin{document}

\huge{\large This paragraph has large text size, but has even huger line spread.}

\tiny{\huge The text size here is huge, but the line spread is so tiny that the
result will probably be overlapping lines.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It might be worth pointing out (unless I'm mistaken) that the relevant line spread is drawn from the active font size when the closing `\par` takes hold.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes well not really from the font size (at the tex level_ but  the latex size commands set both the font size and the baselineskip, so in the first case above `\huge` sets the font and the skip, then locally `\large` resets it but then they are restored at the `}` so at the end of paragraph the baseline skip set by `\huge` is the one in force.

Comment: Well, that's what I meant, even if it didn't come out that way `:^b`